# How to I apply multiple filter criteria based on condition to copy values from other columns into new columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have suppose cols: A,B,C,D,E,F
i.e If in col A == '', make new col G = col C,new col H = col D,new col I = col E
if in col A !='' & col B == 'some-value' ,make col G=0,col H=0, col I=0..
tried using np.where but it supports two condtions only any idea.

```
def change(dfr):

  if (dfr['A']==''): 
    dfr['G'] = dfr['A']
    dfr['H'] = dfr['B']
    dfr['I'] = dfr['C']
  if ((dfr['A']!='') & (dfr['B']=='some-value')): 
    dfr['G'] = dfr['A']
    dfr['H'] = dfr['B']
    dfr['I'] = dfr['C']
  if ((dfr['A']!='') & (dfr['B']=='value')):
    dfr['G'] = 0
    dfr['H'] = 0
    dfr['I'] = 0
```

Comment: [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)?

Comment: not able to make use of it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need the `if` statements. You can use `.loc` to accomplish this. Here is a toy dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"A" : ['a', '', 'f', '4', '', 'z'],
                    "B" : ['f', 'y', 't', 'u', 'o', '1'],
                    "C" : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],                   
                    "G" : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                    'H' : [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
                    "I" : ['q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q']})

data

   A  B  C  G  H  I
0  a  f  a  1  6  q
1     y  b  1  6  q
2  f  t  c  1  6  q
3  4  u  d  1  6  q
4     o  e  1  6  q
5  z  1  f  1  6  q
```

It probably makes sense to build in a couple of arguments for the values you'd like to check for in columns B:

```
def change(dfr, b_firstvalue, b_secondvalue):  
    new_df = dfr.copy()
    new_df.loc[new_df['A']=='', 'G'] = new_df['A'] 
    new_df.loc[new_df['A']=='', 'H'] = new_df['B']
    new_df.loc[new_df['A']=='', 'I'] = new_df['C']

    new_df.loc[((new_df['A']!='') & (new_df['B'] == b_firstvalue)), 'G'] = new_df['A']
    new_df.loc[((new_df['A']!='') & (new_df['B'] == b_firstvalue)), 'H'] = new_df['B']
    new_df.loc[((new_df['A']!='') & (new_df['B'] == b_firstvalue)), 'I'] = new_df['C']

    new_df.loc[((new_df['A']!='') & (new_df['B'] == b_secondvalue)), 'G'] = 0
    new_df.loc[((new_df['A']!='') & (new_df['B'] == b_secondvalue)), 'H'] = 0
    new_df.loc[((new_df['A']!='') & (new_df['B'] == b_secondvalue)), 'I'] = 0
    return new_df

data2 = change(data, '1', 'f')

data2

   A  B  C  G  H  I
0  a  f  a  0  0  0
1     y  b     y  b
2  f  t  c  1  6  q
3  4  u  d  1  6  q
4     o  e     o  e
5  z  1  f  z  1  f
```

Obviously, the function will depend on exactly how many columns you want to deal with. This was just a solution for the example problem.  If you have many more columns you'd like to replace values with, there may be more efficient ways of handling that.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! I'd appreciate if you could accept my answer if you feel that it was the solution to your problem. If not, I could try to improve it if you need further elaboration.